# Traefik configuration with Docker not working

Tags: docker, traefik

I am trying to set up a sample application with the Traefik reverse proxy in Docker.

I am using [Traefik v2.2](https://hub.docker.com/_/traefik) for this project which has significant differences from Traefik.v1.0.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.2
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "89:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8089:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
  whoami:
    # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
```

I can access Traefik's dashboard when I go to `localhost:8089` on my web browser, but I cannot access the `whoami` application when I type in the `whoami.localhost` address on my web browser. I'm just wondering if there is anything I need to change before I can access it, or do I need to change the host from `whoami.localhost` to `localhost:3000` since that's the port I want to access the application in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem I am spotting is that you exposed container port `80` of the traefik container to the host port `89`. If you type in `whoami.localhost` in your web browser, your browser is going to search for an application on host port `80` at that address (since `localhost` maps natively to port `80`), but it is not going to find anything there, because it can only be found at port `89`. From my understanding, you should be able to access the application via the command line with the command `curl -H Host:whoami.localhost http://127.0.0.1:89`. Unfortunately, I am unsure how the URL `whoami.localhost:89` is handled by your browser respectively by your DNS.

You can to modify the `docker-compose.yml` file this way:

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.2
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "89:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8089:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  whoami:
    # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.localhost`)
```

And then you can access the application on your command terminal by typing in:

```
curl -H Host:whoami.localhost http://127.0.0.1:89
```

**Note**: `whoami.localhost` can be `whoami.docker.localhost` or `app.localhost` or whatever you want. The thing here is that you should `localhost` attached to the end, except if you're adding a Fully Qualifies Domain name (FQDN).

That's all.

**I hope this helps**